# Simple search with Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, search, search-engine, keyword

What is the **problem** with this query and how can I **fix** it?

```
public JsonResult Find(string q)
{
    var k = new List<string>(q.Split(' '));

    return Json(_dataContext.Jobs
        .OrderBy(p => new List<string>(p.Keywords.Split(' ')).Where(n => k.Contains(n)).Count())
        .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.IsFullTime, p.Location, p.Category, p.Url, p.Id }),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

It throws:

> Method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

It's supposed to order the results by shared words between `q` and the `Keywords` for each row so the more you have shared words, you are ordered higher.

Thanks.

**BTW:** If it's possible to use Lucene.NET to improve this code, I'd happy to see a short example :)

Comment: Unrelated to your question: You don’t need the `new List<T>` everywhere. You can just use the result of `Split` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > .OrderBy(p => new List(p.Keywords.Split(' ')).

Well, the message is faily clear.  String.Split() cannot be translated into SQL.

There is no really good way to do that in a single Linq-to-Sql statement.  I'd suggest pulling the data out using L2S, put it into a List<>, and then sort them there.

```
    var jobs  = from p in _dataContext.Jobs
    select new 
      {
        p.Title,
        p.IsFullTIme,
        p.Location,
        p.Category,
        p.Url,
        p.Id,
        p.Keywords
      }

      return Json(job.ToList()
            .OrderBy(p=>p.Keywords.Split(' ').Where(n=>k.Contains(n)).Count()),
             JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However, your real problem is that you have a really bad design.  Proper third-normal form would have a JobKeywords table  (int JobId, varchar Keyword) with one row for *each* keyword for a job.   Then you could do it in one sql statement:

```
 return Json(from p in _dataContext.Jobs     
             order by p.Keywords.Intersect(k).Count()
             select new { p.Title, p.IsFullTime, p.Location, 
                          p.Category, p.Url, p.Id },     
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the data from SQL-land and do the string-splitting in C#-land:

```
public JsonResult Find(string q)
{
    var k = q.Split(' ');

    return Json(_dataContext.Jobs
        // Select all the columns we need, including Keywords
        // (still in SQL-land)
        .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.IsFullTime, p.Location, p.Category,
                           p.Url, p.Id, p.Keywords })
        // Move into C#-land
        .AsEnumerable()
        // Do the sorting here in C#-land
        .OrderBy(p => p.Keywords.Split(' ').Count(n => k.Contains(n)))
        // Finally, remove the Keywords column we no longer need
        .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.IsFullTime, p.Location, p.Category,
                           p.Url, p.Id }),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

However, this is going to be slow because it is going to retrieve the **entire** Jobs table every time, even if you add a `.Take(n)` at the end to get only the top *n* entries.

Comment: The original was going to return the entire Job table also.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` just returns the same list. There is no operation defined like that on `IQueryable`. You will need to use `ToList` (or friends) to do the actual retrieval. The `AsEnumerable` does however allow the transistion from SQL to .NET to be made on the subsequent call due to the arguments being delegates.

Comment: @Ieppie: You’re right, `AsEnumerable()` doesn’t actually do the retrieval, but I think that’s not important here. There’s certainly no need for a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `p.Keywords.Split(' ')`. LINQ-to-SQL doesn't support it. And why are you ordering by a list anyway?